# Change in average when memers in a group are changed.

Tags: linear-algebra

> > The average age of women at a tea party is 58. When three women leave
> >     early and two join after those three have left, the average age of the
> >     women becomes 60. What is the difference between the sum of the ages
> >     of the group of three who left and that of the group of two who
> >     joined?
>
> source:
>   https://gehucsit.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/averages-wt-avg-qb.pdf
>   (question no.30)
>
> Answer given: $30$

But I am not sure how the answer can be 30.

To me, answer depends on number of women. For example, If there are 30 women, the difference is zero as given below

> Total age: 58×30=1740
>
> The difference in age = 0
>
> New total: 1740
>
> New average =1740/29=60
>
> So answer can not be found out.

The below answer from this [site](http://goo.gl/P19VBB) also support my argument.

> They have expressed the required difference as $2n-60$ where n is the
>   initial number of women

So, am I correct here? please help. I would not have got this doubt. But two different answers from two sites and hence I wanted to clarify.

Comment: I also think that you're correct.

Comment: 58n + Sum = 60(n-1). Two unknowns with one equation - no solution. I believe the question is in error. Assuming the sum change is 0 you get the number of women 30 in the original group.

Comment: The averages being whole numbers implies this is a diophantine equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{\forall n}{\frac{x_n}{n}}=58$$

$$1: \sum x=58n$$

$$2: \sum y=60(n-1)$$

Find $\sum y - \sum x$$

$$3: \sum y - \sum x=60(n-1) - 58n = 2n -60$$

Can 1,2,3 be solved as diophantine equations to show $n=45$?